# Executable JAR File concern?

Tags: java, file, jar

I have a project and i want to make it available for everyone. Do jar files only work if there is a jdk or java installed or should i make the file windows exe Sorry i'm a newbie when it comes to windows related files?

```
 public static  void main(String[] args)   { 
 System.out.println("Hellowordld");
 }
```

Comment: Anyone with the JRE installed should be able to run JAR files by double-clicking them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to execute a jar file, all you need is a JRE - you can download on Oracles's web site. You can use the JRE that comes inside your JDK too, but remember, not everyone will have a JKD(this is for development), they will probable download a JRE and execute the installation tool.
You don't need do make an exe, especially if you have Linux users too. The jar is enough.